how to calculate the number of reactions to a message in a telegram?(aiogram)
The documentation describes very little and it is not clear how to use it. I would like some examples
@router.message_reaction_count()
async def message_reaction_count_handler(message_reaction_count: types.MessageReactionCountUpdated) -> Any: pass

The documentation says only this

You need at least a minimally working example of how to count reactions
